# Assign Values Based on Variable Name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 data frames. I want to assign the values I got from one of the data frame (alpha, epsilon, and lambda) to another based on participant name (X1,X2,X3). There are 180 X1,X2....X30 in the data frame I want to put values in. So I need 180 X1 in the main data frame have a common value of alpha in column alpha from the data frame of the picture below, a common value of epsilon in column epsilon, ect.

> ori_try <- ori %>% mutate(alpha = res_1$alpha)
>   Error: Column alpha must be length 5400 (the number of rows) or one, not 30'

Comment: Why not share some illustrative data?

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. Have a look at [MRE] for guidance on how you can help the SO community help you.